# xml skip root element

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xstream

So I have the following xml format in a string:

```
<applist>
    <app stuff="blah"/>
    <app stuff="blah"/>
</applist>
```

I am wanting to have a list of `app`

So I am doing this:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("applist", List.class);
List<Application> list = (List<Application>) xstream.fromXML(xml); //xml is what is above
```

And then here is my entity object:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "app")
public class Application{

    private String stuff;

    public String getStuff() {
        return stuff;
    }
    public void setStuff(String stuff) {
        this.stuff = stuff;
    }
}
```

I thought that the `xstream.alias("applist", List.class);` was supposed to ignore the root element... in this case `applist`. However, this is not working and I am getting this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main"   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: app : app
---- Debugging information ----
message             : app
cause-exception     :   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : app
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type      :  com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
path                : /applist/app
line number         : 4
version             : null
-------------------------------
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1058)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1042)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:913)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:904)
at TestStuff.main(TestStuff.java:19)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: app
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:56)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:45)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:70)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.addCurrentElementToCollection(CollectionConverter.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.unmarshal(CollectionConverter.java:61)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
... 10 more
```

So why am I getting this exception? I would think that it would parse pretty nicely like this.

**UPDATE:**

I added `xstream.alias("app", Application.class);` and it is now putting the objects into the list. However, the value of `stuff` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a system using XStream and I didn't find major issues, it is a great library to work with XML :)

I believe you do not need to register "`List.class`" but just your "`Application.class`".

I would do the following:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
xstream.alias("app", Application.class);
xStream.useAttributeFor(Application.class, "stuff");
List<Application> list = (List<Application>) xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

Let me know if that works for you. Happy coding!!!

Comment: No luck with that... I get this: `Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: applist`

Comment: Have you tried annotate your "stuff" variable with @XStreamAsAttribute?

Comment: yep! And still nothing.

Comment: I made an update in the code, I explicitly specified the attribute for your class Application. Let me know if that makes the trick for you.

Comment: the value is still `null` any other ideas?

Comment: I ended up just parsing each app manually. Feel free to up vote so maybe we can get an answer.